# Four students are in a class. Compute the probability of the event

Tags: probability

Four students are in a class. Compute the probability of the event that:

1) at least one of them is born on a Saturday

2) at least 2 of them are born on the same day of the week(e.g on a Sunday)

3) all four of them are born during the weekend(i.e on Saturday or Sunday)

These are my solutions:

1) 1/7 + 1/7+ 1/7 + 1/7 = 57%

2) 1/7 * 1/7 = 2.04%

3) 2/7 * 2/7 * 2/7 * 2/7 = 0.66%

Are these correct?

Thank you

Comment: Only the last one is correct. As for the first one, do you think that if there were 8 students in the class, there would then be an $8/7$ chance that at least one was born on a Saturday?

Comment: 1) this answer has some double counting, and overstates the answer.  Consider instead the chance that none are born on a Saturday.  2) is radically understated.  If there are only 2 people there is a 1/7 chance they are born on the same day of the week.   What is the probability all were born on different days of the week?  3) Is correct.

Comment: @MeesdeVries so the solution to the first event is 1/7 and to the second event is 2/7 ?

Comment: @zeeks No.  Look up Binomial Distribution.

Answer (score 1):

Some hints:

- What is the negation of the first statement?  (If the statement is "At least one was born on a Saturday," what is the opposite of that?)
- Let's call one statement $Q$ and its negation $\neg Q$.  Then, $P(Q) = 1 - P(\neg Q)$.
- What is the negation of the second statement?

Answer (score -1):

I was thinking of this for the first one:

53 saturdays in a year -> 4 people in a class

1/53 + 1/53 + 1/53 + 1/53 =7.5%

Comment: but there's 1 saturday in a week, 1/1 + 1/1 + 1/1 + 1/1= 400%. There's also 5200 saturdays in 100 years, so 1/5200 + 1/5200 + 1/5200 + 1/5200 = 0.0769230769%